# How do you use the differential_drive package

Tags: ros, differential-drive

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked at the ros documentation for the package but found the documentation was outdated, so I'm asking how do you use it in Noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392554/how-do-you-use-the-differential_drive-package/) by [bribri123](https://answers.ros.org/users/78090/bribri123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @bribri123,

> differential_drive

This package has reached its EOL as it provides support for only [ROS Groovy and ROS Fuerte](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller). If you are using ros noetic then you should consider packages like [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller).

You can install this via:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-diff-drive-controller
```

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0